# Fixing Whirlpool front loader washing machine. Error at start of 2nd rinse fill

Tags: washing-machine

Whirlpool Duet, front loader, 
Model WFW9150ww00
Serial HLY4930303
Type 832-A

Manufactured around 28 January 2010

The washing machine shows the following symptoms:
Washes normally, will do the first rinse, then at the start of the second rinse will stop and sound 3 short beeps.  It will repeat this every few seconds until you power cycle it.

If you start it immediately (power on, then start) it will unlock door, then relock door, and go back to triple beep.

The manual for it talks about error codes.  But they are in the form of half second beeps separated by half second pauses.  I've had those before from clogged inlet filters.  This is much faster.  All three beeps take a total of about a second.

If I unplug it instead, and replug I get the  same thing.

If I unplug it and leave it for a while, or if I just power it off to shut it up, and leave it for a while, it starts normally.

This has happened twice before, and on the leave and restart it was then fine for weeks.  This afternoon it has gone through 3 resets, and we have yet to finish a load of wash.

I spent the afternoon between resets on the phone with Whirlpool.  At the end they said I needed a service call.  Alas we are out of the city, and there no service agent that will come out here.  Given the intermittent nature of the problem, I don't want to take it into town.

A:  Can anyone point me to documentation about the 3 short beeps.

B:  Other ideas to what possible causes of a problem starting at the second rinse might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many whirlpool washers the lower front panel removes with three  1/4" hex head sheet metal screws.

Remove the panel.

Inside is a tech diagnostics document.

It will tell you to hit any 3 buttons 3 times in sequence -- ABCABCABC  All the lights will turn on.

Press button A

The wash light will blink the error code in 1/2 second pulses, a 2 second pause, a second set of half second pulses a longer pause and will repeat.

In my case the error code was 9 2.

Looking this up in the technical document said 'drain problems, suggested checking a wiring harness, and some connectors, also to check the drain filter.

Since the multimeter was in the garage, and the filter in front of me, I removed the filter (This will discharge a quart of really gross water. Tilting the washing machine back and putting 2x4's under the legs will reduce this a bunch.

Inside the debris trap I found a $5, a $10, and a $20 bill, in pieces, along with $13 in change.

Cleaned this out along with a small fur ball, and reassembled.  No problems since.

---

Additional information Christmas 2019

The problem went away and has come back several times. At this time I suspect that the soap detector is expecting a given reading on a given rinse.  Changing brands of soap, and measuring carefully helps.